# Objective C Date Conversion From String

Tags: ios, objective-c, date-conversion

I am very new to Objective C.

I am passing date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" from webservice to apps (Objective C). How do I convert this to date format in Objective C?

Some help would be appreciated. :)

Regards,
SG

Comment: A Google could have saved you from writing this question! stop flooding SO!

Comment: He or she just wants a personal reply, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "dateFromString" function as below:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-02-06"]; 
[formatter release];
```